# How to read messages from Telegram group with bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to connect a simple telegram bot to read messages from a group, (where I'm not admin). I already added the bot to the group, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code I have in Python:

```py
import telepot
from pprint import pprint
import time
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

key = "MY API"

bot = telepot.Bot(key)

def handle(msg):
   print(msg)

bot.message_loop(handle)

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

If I open the chat (of the bot) and write a message, everything works well. But when someone send a message in a group (where I added the bot), even if the bot is in that group, nothing happen. What I'm doing wrong? Do I miss something?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `/setprivacy` to `Disable`, or you can only receive command (starts with `/`).

You can refer to [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you re-add your bot to group?

Comment: Yes yes, but somehow it doesn't work properly. If I add it in a new group (created by me), I can read everything, but if I add it in another group (where I'm not admin), I can't read messages, only information like "users x joined the group". Do you think is related to the permission of that group?

Comment: works for me, thank you! Note: you can also set this option via the botfather. Also, if you try to delete group messages, make bot admin with priviledge to delete messages.

Answer (score 2):

Your telegram bot should be the admin of group to be able to read messages of the group.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in [Telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot) framework. You can do something like this in your favorite framework.

```
def handle(msg):
    if msg['chat']['id'] == -1001136714808:
        print(msg['text'])
```